# How do you find the greatest rectangle of given ratios that can be cut from another fixed rectangle?

Tags: calculus, optimization, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

I have a $22\text{cm} \times 28\text{cm}$ piece of paper. I want to cut out the largest rectangle from it whose length to breadth ratio is

$11:\sqrt 3$

How do I go about doing it? What will be the size of the sides and the angle with which it is inclined to the side of the paper?

At first I thought it would be parallel to the diagonal of the paper and have all corners touching the sides of the paper, but that's not the case right?

Comment: I think it is the case. Can you give a construction that does better?